# ASP issue in retrieving datas

Tags: ms-access, asp-classic

```
set rs6= objconn.execute("select TotalDays from newbank where " & _   
          "newbank.empid= '" & session("EmpID") & "' and newbank.LeaveType = 23")
```

Here 23 is the value in the Field named LeaveType, but TotalDays are not being retrieved. Can you help to solve this?

Thank You

Comment: Can you run this query against the database using the query design window and see if anything is returned?

Comment: how to you open the connection to the db? do you use ADO?

Comment: This code is extremely vulnerable to sql injection

Answer (score 0):

save sql and variables to a string first

```
EmpID = session("EmpID")
sql = "select TotalDays from newbank where empid= '" & EmpID & "' and LeaveType = 23"
log(EmpID )
log(sql)
```

Must EmpID be a string ?
log is your debugging or logging routine you unbdoubtly have..
session and request variables are best placed in a stringvariable first so you're sure of the type and can inspect the contents

like suggested above test the contents op the sql var againt your database, if it works there perhaps something is wrong with your connectionsetup